# local reference to this?

Tags: javascript, this

Why does 'this' need a local reference?  The first code segment works fine but the second code segment thows an error...  you're creating a reference (not being passed by value) so you would be modifying the same object prototype which is what you're trying to do anyways... not sure where the error is coming from...

Difference in code is the first few lines of each segment

First Code Segment:

```
Function.prototype.construct = function(aArgs) {
  var a = this;  
  var fNewConstr = function() { a.apply(this, aArgs); };
  fNewConstr.prototype = a.prototype;
  return new fNewConstr();
};

function MyConstructor() {
  for (var nProp = 0; nProp < arguments.length; nProp++) {
    this['property' + nProp] = arguments[nProp];
  }
}

var myArray = [4, 'Hello world!', false];
var myInstance = MyConstructor.construct(myArray);
```

Second Code Segment:

```
Function.prototype.construct = function(aArgs) {  
  var fNewConstr = function() { this.apply(this, aArgs); };
  fNewConstr.prototype = this.prototype;
  return new fNewConstr();
};

function MyConstructor() {
  for (var nProp = 0; nProp < arguments.length; nProp++) {
    this['property' + nProp] = arguments[nProp];
  }
}

var myArray = [4, 'Hello world!', false];
var myInstance = MyConstructor.construct(myArray);
```

Comment: Because `fNewConstr` is an extra function with its own `this`

Comment: Thanks, I should have seen that... if you turn your comment into a response, I can indicate it as the correct answer

Comment: Actually @Pointy has already given a pretty extensive answer stating very much the same :-)

Comment: To be completely honest... you being able to answer the question in a 10 word, very straight forward response was much more useful (in this case) than his 283 word response... obviously it's not always the case that the very short explanation is best when things actually require that kind of detail, but this is not one of those cases... 

I'll mark his as the correct answer for now, but if you want to make a response, I'll switch the credit to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first bit of code, your "construct" method, the value of `this` will be the function from which you invoke it.  It's *not* the newly-constructed object that the function intends to return from its internal constructor.

The value of `this` is set for each function call, depending on the nature of the call. You're calling "fNewConstr" via `new`, so the value of `this` in that function is the object being constructed. In order to correctly apply the original "root" function to the newly-created object, it requires a reference to that function. That's what's saved in "a".

Step by step, when you call

```
MyConstructor.construct(myArray);
```

what happens is:

1. The symbol "MyConstructor" is examined and found to be a reference to an object — a function, in fact.
2. The `.` operator results in the property "construct" being looked up, first on the "MyConstructor" function object itself and then on the object's prototype, where the property name will be found.
3. The value of that "construct" property is a function, so the `( )` operator launches a function call.
4. Now we're inside "construct", and `this` is a reference to the function "MyConstructor".  That reference  is immediately copied to "a".
5. The "fNewConstr" variable is initialized and then immediately invoked via `new`. A new object is created and now *that* function call is launched, with `this` referring to that new object.
6. Inside "fNewConstr", "a" still refers to "MyConstructor", so that reference lets the runtime find the "apply" function on the Function prototype. Now *that* function is launched, and we'll finally end up in the "MyConstructor" code.
7. Inside "MyConstructor", `this` will refer to the object constructed with the `new` operation, and the parameters will be the elements of the array passed in originally.